# Rewriting "SELECT DISTINCT ON ..." using Django's ORM

Tags: sql, django, orm

I am using the following model with Django:

```
class Hit(Model):
    image = ForeignKey(Image)
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

What I need is basically a list that contains the count of "first hits" (i.e. hits with no earlier timestamp for the same image) for every user to create sort of a rank list.

Or still easier, just a list that contains a user name one time for every time this user has made a "first hit".

In SQL using the PostgreSQL "DISTINCT ON" extension, this would be a simple query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (image_id) user_id FROM proj_hit ORDER BY image_id ASC, timestamp ASC;
```

It there a way, to get this result with Django's ORM or (at least) portable SQL, i.e. no PostgreSQL extensions?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question but would a list of all the "first hits" be a good starting point? From this, you could obtain a list of all the Users responsible for the Hits, as each Hit refers to a single User.

Comment: Yes, a list of all the first hits should suffice. From there, I can do a join to get the users and then the usual grouping and COUNT aggregation to get the numbers of first hits per user. But how can I get a list of all first hits? I've been thinking about this the last hours but I just can't figure it out. Maybe I'm not experienced enough with the Django ORM way of thinking. PS: Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you at liberty to make a change to your model? It  would help to de-normalize and store the first hit information in the same model or as part of a different model.

For e.g.

```
class Hit(Model):
    image = ForeignKey(Image)
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    is_first_hit = BooleanField(default = False)
```

You can then override the `save()` method (or tap a signal) to set the `is_first_hit` explicitly on save. This would make inserts and updates a little more expensive but would make querying very easy.

Comment: Surprisingly I haven't thought of that, but it's a really good idea. The additional BooleanField won't hurt and denormalizing will neither because my app is the only one editing the database and I can still write a consistency checking script if I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the portable SQL version is very similar to the version that you posted — simply drop the `ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT image_id, user_id FROM proj_hit ORDER BY image_id ASC, timestamp ASC;
```

Comment: Well, in SQLite this works, however in PostgreSQL not: "ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list" - Django is doing the same thing: If you call distinct() on a query set that has been order_by()ed before, the ordering columns are automatically added to the distinct set. For me, this means, that I would not get "first hits" but "all hits" since the timestamp differs between the hits and so they are treated as different according to distinct.